# Receiving a vague syntax error when Seeding with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have stared this code for too long and I'm not even sure what the issue is. Is there a way I can get better logs than this vague `syntax error at or near ")"` ?? It's killing me that it won't even tell me the line that it's on. Or what part of the SQL is giving the issue.

Notes: The queries that I run in here are returning just fine. It seems to be the case that it's when I try to insert the giftCardEmailTemplateArr is where things get messed up.

Thank you for the help in advance. I'm still new so any other tips would be super helpful as well.

```
"use strict";
var casual = require("casual");
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    const getSettings = async () => {
      await queryInterface.sequelize
        .query(`SELECT * from settings;`)
        .then((res) => {
          // console.log("settings", res[0]);
          console.log("successful setting query");
          settings = res[0];
        });
    };

    const generateGiftCardEmailTemplate = async () => {
      console.log("generating array");

      settings.forEach(async (setting) => {
        let user = null;
        await queryInterface.sequelize
          .query(
            `SELECT * 
          FROM users 
          WHERE "role"= 'owner' AND "companyId" = '${setting.companyId}'`
          )
          .then((res) => {
            // console.log("users", res[0][0]);
            user = res[0][0];
            console.log("successful user query");
          })
          .catch((err) =>
            console.log("found in creation of template", err)
          );

        const gCEmailTemplateObj = {
          id: casual.uuid,
          fromName: user.username,
          fromEmail: user.email,
          logo: `https://i.picsum.photos/id/${casual.integer(
            101,
            999
          )}/250/250.jpg`,
          subject: casual.words(4),
          title: casual.words(2),
          body: casual.sentences(3),
          cta: casual.url,
          emailFooter: casual.words(6),
          companyId: setting.companyId,
          settingId: setting.id,
          updatedAt: new Date(),
          createdAt: new Date(),
        };
        giftCardEmailTemplateArr.push(gCEmailTemplateObj);
      });
    };
    const seedEmailTemplate = () => {
      queryInterface
        .bulkInsert(
          "giftCardEmailTemplates",
          giftCardEmailTemplateArr,
          {}
        )
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("found in putting of templates", err);
          console.log("piece of array", giftCardEmailTemplateArr);
        });
    };
    let giftCardEmailTemplateArr = [];
    let settings = null;
    await getSettings();
    await generateGiftCardEmailTemplate();
    return seedEmailTemplate();
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete(
      "giftCardEmailTemplates",
      null,
      {}
    );
  },
};
```

The error I'm receiving

```
original: error: syntax error at or near ")"
      at Connection.parseE (C:\Users\Chris\Documents\GitHub\giftcards-web\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:581:48)
      at Connection.parseMessage (C:\Users\Chris\Documents\GitHub\giftcards-web\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:380:19)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Chris\Documents\GitHub\giftcards-web\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:116:22)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:12)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:268:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
    length: 90,
    severity: 'ERROR',
    code: '42601',
    detail: undefined,
    hint: undefined,
    position: '39',
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: 'scan.l',
    line: '1149',
    routine: 'scanner_yyerror',
    sql: 'INSERT INTO "giftCardEmailTemplates" () VALUES ;',
    parameters: undefined
  },
  sql: 'INSERT INTO "giftCardEmailTemplates" () VALUES ;',
  parameters: undefined
```

Comment: Your `INSERT` statement is clearly missing the list of columns to update. That's the error.

Comment: That `.forEach()` loop is not going to wait for the queries to finish, also.

Comment: What am I missing that would allow my for each loop to finish? 

Would that then resolve the issue of my insert statement not working?

Comment: The `.forEach()` callback is performing asynchronous operations. You can instead use `.map()` to create an array of Promise objects, and then use `Promise.all()` to wait for all of them to finish.